# wordpress cannot connect to remote azure centos virtual host

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

I have two windows azure CentOS hosts in the same affinity group and on the same private subnet.  I am unable to get wordpress to connect to the db from the apache webserver.  I continually get "Error Establishing Database Connection".  I can connect from the webserver mysql client to the db on the private network, but I cannot get the php connection to the db.

Any assistance is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

SELinux was the issue.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```